# Is docker volume deleted if the container is deleted?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I'm reading the book `The docker book` version `v1.2.0`, in chapter 6 in page 178 it said that

> if you deleted the last container that uses a volume, the volume will disappear. Be carful about deleting containers that might hold volumes with data you need

But when I tried it, the volume isn't deleted.
Is that just because I'm reading old version ??

Comment: There might be some context that makes the statement true, but generally, the whole point of volumes is to persist data when containers stop. Deleting the volume would make very little sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer versions will not delete your volume, unless you're using the parameter `--volumes` or `-v`.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/#options